# Replacing something with a fragment

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments, fragment

If I replace (let's say) a TextView by a fragment by this piece of code:

```
transaction.replace(R.id.TextView01, fragment1);
```

Does the new fragment (which is now visible in the layout) have the same id of the replaced one? (in this case, it's R.id.TextView01).

It might seem like nonsense, but I have this action set up as an action on a button and pressing it repeately doesn't cause any errors.

So, does it have the id of the replaced one or it just doesn't replace when I click several times (because the fragment has got it's unique id)?

Comment: When you set a new fragment, you should also give it a string tag that you can use to refer to later;

Comment: As far as I know, there are two transaction methods to replace:
replace(id, fragment, tag) and replace(id, fragment). In the second one is the tag set to null (according to documentation). So which id should be reffered to?

Comment: Slightly confused as to why you'd replace a `TextView` with a `Fragment`. A `TextView` is a fairly dumb UI widget whereas a `Fragment` has intelligence approaching that of an `Activity`. I could understand replacing a `Fragment` which contains just a single `TextView` with another `Fragment` but not replacing a `TextView` with a `Fragment`. Also, no...the id of the `TextView` is its own regardless of whether it is visible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `replace(id, fragment)` you don't replace the `id` but the `view`. The 1st param is `int containerViewId` which it serve to:

> *Identifier of the container whose fragment(s) are to be replaced*

This is just the container. As you can propably know, replace method is the combinaison of `remove` and `add` methods. When you look at the `remove` method, you can read:

> *Remove an existing fragment. If it was added to a container, its view is also removed from that container.*

You use `remove(Fragment fragment)`, you don't use any `id`. Also, "from that container" means that the container is not removed on the layout, so you don't use any `id` and less the container id.
The only way to have an "id" is to use:

```
replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)
```

The `String tag` allows you to retrieve this fragment with `findFragmentByTag(String)`.
Finally, as @Squonk said, it's really "ugly" to replace a `TextView` with `Fragment`, and even more with view groups like `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, etc. The only "right" way to display a fragment is the `FrameLayout` which:

> *is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item.*

If you search a little `FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, etc extend `ViewGroup` but the only one which can contain a fragment and overlap the views it's the `FrameLayout` (like a special ViewGroup).

Answer (score 0):

`Fragments` are not `Views`. Views should have unique ids and Fragments should have unique ids in themselves. But a Fragment may have a Views id in most of the cases.

In your case, yes they have the same id.

But I think they may be an additional problem here. When the `Fragments` view is inflated, the view will be added as a child in the id provided. Since your view is only a `TextView` and it does not support childviews, I am not sure the Fragment is `actually` added here.